# Stored Procedure to SELECT Last 6 Digits of Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a data field in a SQL table with a large number (9 digits, A Customer Information Number). I want to run a stored procedure that will only SELECT the last 6 digits of the number.

Something like:

```
SELECT (Last 6 Digits of num) FROM db
WHERE user = @user
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use the `RIGHT()` function, it takes in a variable and the number of digits you want. In your case `RIGHT(myField, 6)`.  See my answer

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? It looks like probably MS SQL Server, but you should probably tag the question so that people know, unless you're looking for a strictly ANSI SQL answer.

Comment: Ah Yes, I am using MS SQL Server. My bad

Comment: I edited your post to include the `sql-server` tag

Comment: Rather than splitting on the fly, consider storing the sub elements of the value in separate columns then concatenating them via a `VIEW`, computed column, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
DECLARE @bigOne bigint

SET @bigOne = 999333444

SELECT RIGHT(@bigOne, 6)
```

Returns the right part of a character string with the specified number of characters.
Here is the MSDN for the `Right()` function as well: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx

In your case corey you can do:

`SELECT RIGHT(num, 6) FROM db WHERE user=@user`

Just replace `num` with the name of your column from your database table, and change `db` to the name of your table that you are `SELECT`ing from.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) operator to easily extract the last 6 digits assuming `num` is a numeric datatype:

```
select num % 1000000 as num
from db
where user = ?
```

Comment: It's faster than a string conversion when you're working with a numeric datatype.

Comment: Only detail is that this will suppress leading zeros in those digits and the string answers will leave them in.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL Server,

```
SELECT subtring(num,len(num)-6,6) FROM db
WHERE user = @user
```

Other flavors may use `substr` instead of `substring`.

Comment: Why do you make additional calls to `Len()` etc, just use `Right()` and pull the right 6 digits.

Comment: Oh wow I never knew SQL Server had `right`... Still my answer works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to a string then use SUBSTRING and LEN to pull only the piece you need.

Comment: This seems rather expensive, a cast, a length, and a substring to get the last 6 digits of a number?

Answer (score 0):

This will accurately get the last 6 digits from the argument you pass.

One thing to note.  In SQL Server 2005, the "\" (backslash) character does not return 1 by ISNUMERIC.  But it does in SQL Server 2008.  This function should work in both versions of SQL Server since we're simply excluding this character in the 7th piece of my test argument above.

PRINT RIGHT(dbo.fnNumericDigits('5-555-555551-2345-6-'), 6)

**Scalar-valued Function:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnNumericDigits]
(
    @startString NVARCHAR(255)
) RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @returnString NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @length INT, @currentDigit INT, @currentCharacter NVARCHAR(1)
    SELECT @length = LEN(@startString), @currentDigit = 1, @returnString = ''

    WHILE @currentDigit <= @length
    BEGIN

    SELECT @currentCharacter = SUBSTRING(@startString, @currentDigit, @currentDigit)

    IF ISNUMERIC(@currentCharacter) = 1 
        AND @currentCharacter != '$'
        AND @currentCharacter != '+'
        AND @currentCharacter != ','
        AND @currentCharacter != '-'
        AND @currentCharacter != '.'
        AND @currentCharacter != '\'
    BEGIN
    SELECT @returnString = @returnString + @currentCharacter
    END

    SELECT @currentDigit = @currentDigit + 1

END

RETURN @returnString
END
```